# Streaming from sub-set of partitions within a topic (Kafka Streams)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I've got a question about design.
We are working on building Kafka dedupe processing.

As far as I understand leveraging Kafka Stream is the possible API candidate.
Our topics are divided into 100 partitions. To scale the process we are examining an option,
a single Docker container (K8S pod) as a processing task per partition or group of partitions.

My question is if Kafka Stream API allows creating a stream from a specific topic.
Since our time window is very long (2 weeks) then the stateful process store grows to a large size.

Will appreciate any idea, what is the most proper way how to tackle it.

Comment: Are you looking for `builder.stream("specific-topic")`? There's no way to assign specific _partitions_

Comment: is there any workaround to achieve such functionality, honestly I'm very surprised that the Kafka Streams API doesn't allow this.

Comment: One option is to use something like MirrorMaker to first copy one topic into another smaller topic (probably going to need a custom partitioner). Then build a stream from that. I can't think of a good alternative other than just consuming all partitions and somehow filtering them (I assume that would require the Processor API since filter DSL function doesn't give partition information)

Comment: thanks, Jordan, it also was my first thing to start with. Although it looks not trivial. 
Just wanted to ensure I don't miss this functionality in the API.